# Redirect to android webview app when clicked on a link

Tags: android, android-webview

I have built an Android WebView Application on let's say https://example.com. So I have a link like https://example.com/link which when clicked from where so ever have to open in the app rather than in the default browser.

let's say I have clicked on the link https://example.com/link on chrome but I want the link to be opened in my App i.e. just like amazon does, when clicked on its links on chrome it redirects to the app.

Answer (score 0):

Add `WebViewClient` to `WebView` and  override override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

Kotlin example:

```
        binding?.webView?.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                request?.url // handle it here and return true or false depend on if you want webview to load it pr you going to handle it your self
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
            }
        }
```